# How to make a join of my first column TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I would like to create a verification email for my user. However, I don't see how I can make a join in my UserToken table with my user's id using typeorm.

Could someone please explain?

```
@Entity({name: "user_token"})
export class UserToken {
    @PrimaryColumn({name: "user_id"})
    @IsUUID()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userId: UserId


    @Column({name: "token"})
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    token!: string
}
```

```
@Entity({name: "users"})
export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn({name: "id"})
    @IsUUID()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    id!: string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the @ManyToOne() decorator in the UserToken entity, like so:

```
@Entity({ name: 'user_token' })
export class UserToken {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  @IsUUID()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  userId: UserId;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, user => user.userTokens, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;

  @Column({ name: 'token' })
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  token!: string;
}
```

And then modify the User entity like so:

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'id' })
  @IsUUID()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  id!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => UserToken, token => token.user)
  userTokens: UserToken[];
}
```

Since a user can have many tokens (incase one expires), you should have a one to many relationship.

Visit the TypeORM documentation site to learn more about Relations: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relations